# How do I update kernel-utils?

Tags: linux, installation

Brace yourself, I'm a Windows admin messing with a CentOS 6 server.

Let's start by saying I know very little about Linux.

I'm trying to load an rmmagent, GFI/MaxFocus's agent. It's failing the dependency check on kernel-utils and unzip.

error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel-utils is needed by rmmagent-1.0.2.centos6-1.2.x86_64
        unzip is needed by rmmagent-1.0.2.centos6-1.2.x86_64

I Googled myself to death, but I think I just don't know enough about Linux to make this go.

Can someone educate me or point me to the right place to learn how to do this? Thanks!

-Jeff

PS: I got unzip installed without issue.

Comment: Have you tried `yum install kernel-utils unzip`?  Here's a tutorial on "yum", one of the two main Linux package managers: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-102-5/

Comment: CentOS is an `rpm` based distro, so you will have online repositories that contain the various rpm packages (and updates) that are available to your OS. (see: [**Chapter 11. Package Management Tool**](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-graphical-rpm.html) ). Simple insure you have the repositories configured and available for use. Alternatively, if you have the rpm you need to install locally, then it is just `rpm -Uvh somefile.rpm`.

Comment: Here's what I got with yum install kernel-utils:Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
drivesrvr                                                | 2.2 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package kernel-utils available.
Error: Nothing to do
I think I don't know how to load whatever kernel-utils is contained within.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We had the same issue. We spoke to the LogicNow support and they give us this solution:

wget -c ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/9.1/i586/Mandrake/RPMS/ksymoops-2.4.8-1mdk.i586.rpm

yum install ksymoops-2.4.8-1mdk.i586.rpm

Comment: Erik, This helped a lot. I tried to upvote it, but I'm new, so I don't think it counts. I had to re-wire the filename for CentOS but I got the file and it installed just fine. Now the agent won't login, but that's a question for support. Thanks for all the help, everyone!

Comment: Here's where I got the file, in case anyone else trips over this: wget -c ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/hillwood/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/ksymoops-2.4.11-1.1.x86_64.rpm